# SCons with AddOption does not capture all specified flags

Tags: scons

I'm having a problem with [AddOption](http://www.scons.org/doc/2.3.4/HTML/scons-user/ch10.html#sect-command-line-options) in SCons where I am specifying multiple flags for a single option.  It is not picking up one of the flags.  In this example, I want both `-V` and `--verbose` to trip the same option, but it is only working for `--verbose`.

Here is a minimal working example.

`./SConstruct`

```
AddOption("-V", "--verbose",
          action="store_true", dest="verbose", default=False,
          help="Print everything to stdout")
if not GetOption('help'):
    if GetOption('verbose'):
        print '## VERBOSITORY IS ON  ##'
    else:
        print '## VERBOSITORY IS OFF ##'
```

Which when run we get the following...

```
+ scons --help
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
usage: scons [OPTION] [TARGET] ...

SCons Options:
  -b, -d, -e, -m, -S, -t, -w, --environment-overrides, --no-keep-going,
  --no-print-directory, --print-directory, --stop, --touch
                              Ignored for compatibility.
  -c, --clean, --remove       Remove specified targets and dependencies.
  -C DIR, --directory=DIR     Change to DIR before doing anything.
  --cache-debug=FILE          Print CacheDir debug info to FILE.
  --cache-disable, --no-cache
                              Do not retrieve built targets from CacheDir.
  --cache-force, --cache-populate
                              Copy already-built targets into the CacheDir.
  --cache-readonly            Do not update CacheDir with built targets.
  --cache-show                Print build actions for files from CacheDir.
  --config=MODE               Controls Configure subsystem: auto, force,
                                cache.
  -D                          Search up directory tree for SConstruct,
                                build all Default() targets.
  --debug=TYPE                Print various types of debugging information:
                                count, duplicate, explain, findlibs, includes,
                                memoizer, memory, objects, pdb, prepare,
                                presub, stacktrace, time.
  --diskcheck=TYPE            Enable specific on-disk checks.
  --duplicate=DUPLICATE       Set the preferred duplication methods. Must be
                                one of hard-soft-copy, soft-hard-copy,
                                hard-copy, soft-copy, copy
  -f FILE, --file=FILE, --makefile=FILE, --sconstruct=FILE
                              Read FILE as the top-level SConstruct file.
  -h, --help                  Print defined help message, or this one.
  -H, --help-options          Print this message and exit.
  -i, --ignore-errors         Ignore errors from build actions.
  -I DIR, --include-dir=DIR   Search DIR for imported Python modules.
  --implicit-cache            Cache implicit dependencies
  --implicit-deps-changed     Ignore cached implicit dependencies.
  --implicit-deps-unchanged   Ignore changes in implicit dependencies.
  --interact, --interactive   Run in interactive mode.
  -j N, --jobs=N              Allow N jobs at once.
  -k, --keep-going            Keep going when a target can't be made.
  --max-drift=N               Set maximum system clock drift to N seconds.
  --md5-chunksize=N           Set chunk-size for MD5 signature computation to
                                N kilobytes.
  -n, --no-exec, --just-print, --dry-run, --recon
                              Don't build; just print commands.
  --no-site-dir               Don't search or use the usual site_scons dir.
  --profile=FILE              Profile SCons and put results in FILE.
  -q, --question              Don't build; exit status says if up to date.
  -Q                          Suppress "Reading/Building" progress messages.
  --random                    Build dependencies in random order.
  -s, --silent, --quiet       Don't print commands.
  --site-dir=DIR              Use DIR instead of the usual site_scons dir.
  --stack-size=N              Set the stack size of the threads used to run
                                jobs to N kilobytes.
  --taskmastertrace=FILE      Trace Node evaluation to FILE.
  --tree=OPTIONS              Print a dependency tree in various formats: all,
                                derived, prune, status.
  -u, --up, --search-up       Search up directory tree for SConstruct,
                                build targets at or below current directory.
  -U                          Search up directory tree for SConstruct,
                                build Default() targets from local SConscript.
  -v, --version               Print the SCons version number and exit.
  --warn=WARNING-SPEC, --warning=WARNING-SPEC
                              Enable or disable warnings.
  -Y REPOSITORY, --repository=REPOSITORY, --srcdir=REPOSITORY
                              Search REPOSITORY for source and target files.

Local Options:
  -V, --verbose               Print everything to stdout

+ scons --version
SCons by Steven Knight et al.:
    script: v2.3.4, 2014/09/27 12:51:43, by garyo on lubuntu
    engine: v2.3.4, 2014/09/27 12:51:43, by garyo on lubuntu
    engine path: ['/usr/lib/scons/SCons']
Copyright (c) 2001 - 2014 The SCons Foundation

+ scons -v
SCons by Steven Knight et al.:
    script: v2.3.4, 2014/09/27 12:51:43, by garyo on lubuntu
    engine: v2.3.4, 2014/09/27 12:51:43, by garyo on lubuntu
    engine path: ['/usr/lib/scons/SCons']
Copyright (c) 2001 - 2014 The SCons Foundation

+ scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
## VERBOSITORY IS OFF ##
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: `.' is up to date.
scons: done building targets.

+ scons --verbose
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
## VERBOSITORY IS ON  ##
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: `.' is up to date.
scons: done building targets.

+ scons -V
usage: scons [OPTION] [TARGET] ...

SCons Error: no such option: -V
```

So why am I getting an error when passing `-V`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SCons parses the list of arguments several times. Your error stems from the first pass, even before the SConscripts are read in, and only builtin arguments are allowed...so your `AddOption()` doesn't have an effect yet.

In fact, it's impossible to add a short option like "`-V`" by the `AddOption` method in a SConscript. Only the long options, like your "`--verbose`", don't break the build immediately. In `src/engine/Script/SConsOptions.py` the method `SConsOptionParser._process_long_opt()` catches the actual exception, such that in a second try (after reading in all SConscripts/SConstructs) the parsing may succeed.

Comment: So it's a bug in scons?  The users guide says "The AddOption function takes the same arguments as the optparse.add_option function from the standard Python library."  Since my option was taken mostly from the first example in the optparse documentation, I'm thinking this is bug...  Also, I wouldn't say it's impossible to add a short option like -V, as long as I don't use that option, it works just fine, and even shows up in the help dialog.  Admittedly, that's not very useful, but reinforces to me that this is probably a bug.

Comment: You can see it as a bug, sure. But for me it's more a lack of proper documentation. As far as I know, in the SCons docs (*not* the optparse one) you won't find an example of adding a short option...so that gives a clue somewhat. ;) Would you be able to report this as issue to our Tigris bug tracker? Then it's not forgotten and someone can fix the docs.